# Successful Pages after registration in yii controller

Tags: yii

I want to redirect to another pages after successful registration. How I can I restrict this pages to be visited directly from url. only display after registration.

```
public function actionRegistration()
{
   .......
  if($model->save())
  {
    $this->redirect(Yii::app()->request->baseUrl.'/site/success_registration'); 
  }
  ............
} 

public function actionSuccess_registration()
{
   $this->render('success_registration');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could probably add some rules and filters, or you could check the referrer in the actionSuccess_registration but the simplest way to make the view non-accessible from anywhere else would be to render the success_registration view from inside actionRegistration. actionSuccess_registration is therefore redundant if all it does is render the view.

```
public function actionRegistration()
{
  .......
  if($model->save())
  {
    $this->render('success_registration');
    return;
  }
  ............
}
```

Answer (score 0):

check [this](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.auth) out for authentication in yii.
so u could do like this:

```
class YourController extends CController
{
    ......
    public function filters()
    {
        return array(
            'accessControl',
        );
    }

    public function accessRules()
    {
        return array(
            array('deny',
                'actions'=>array('registration'),
                'users'=>array('?'),
            ),
            array('allow',
                'actions'=>array('success_registration'),
                'users'=>array('@'),
            ),
            array('deny',
                'actions'=>array('delete'),
                'users'=>array('*'),
            ),
        );
    }
}
```

in your method

```
public function actionRegistration()
{
   .......
  if($model->save())
  {
    $this->redirect($this->createUrl('site/success_registration')); 
  }
  ............
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be easier if you used flash messages instead. That's what they are there for.

```
public function actionRegister()
{
    if(Yii::app()->user->hasFlash('registered')) {
        $this->render('success_login');
    } else {
        // Process POST registration data here.
        // If registration was successul you do:
        Yii::app()->user->setFlash('registered',true);
        $this->refresh();

        // Otherwhise you render the registration form here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you should go to the project file and go to the protected folder ->controller folder and then open the SiteController.php
please find the  "public action actionLogin()" in the SiteController.php.
after that find this line:

`$this->redirect(Yii::app()->user->returnUrl);`

in the actionLogin() function.

for example i want it is redirect to the user controller.i add `.'?r=user'` at the end of code.

`$this->redirect(Yii::app()->user->returnUrl.'?r=user');`